# expansion of hypergeometric series

Tags: special-functions

I am completely new to mathematica. I am not sure how to calculate the expression 2F1. Is it possible to a closed form solution in terms of z of the hypergeometric series 2F1(-a, N/2-a, N/2; z) and 2F1(1-a, N/2-a, 1+N/2; z) when N>2a and N is any positive natural number.

Comment: Try `Hypergeometric2F1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nmax = 7;

Table[{n, Assuming[n/2 > a, 
      Hypergeometric2F1[-a, n/2 - a, n/2, z] // FunctionExpand // 
       FullSimplify]}, {n, 1, nmax}] // 
   Prepend[#, {"n", Hypergeometric2F1[-a, n/2 - a, n/2, z]}] & // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] & // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Table[{n, Assuming[n/2 > a, 
      Hypergeometric2F1[1 - a, n/2 - a, 1 + n/2, z] // FunctionExpand // 
       FullSimplify]}, {n, 1, nmax}] // 
   Prepend[#, {"n", Hypergeometric2F1[1 - a, n/2 - a, 1 + n/2, z]}] & // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] & // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Consequently, even for specific values of `n` these hypergeometric functions do not generally reduce to simpler functions.

Answer (score 1):

For general $n$ and $a$ no, but for many values it can simplify.  For instance:

```
a = 3/2;

Table[Hypergeometric2F1[-a, n/2 - a, n/2, z] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify, {n, 1, 5}]

{
3 z + 1, 
(8 (z - 1) EllipticK[z] + 2 (z + 7) EllipticE[z])/(3 π), 
1, 
(4 (z - 1) (z + 3) EllipticK[z] + 4 ((7 - 2 z) z + 3) EllipticE[z])/(15 π z),
(Sqrt[z] ((8 - 3 z) z + 3) + 3 (z - 1)^3 ArcTanh[Sqrt[z]])/(16 z^(3/2))
}
```

Capital $N$ is a builtin function in Mathematica, so don't use it as a variable.